# How to use ChosenInlineResultHandler in python telegram bot to handle the send query result?

Tags: callback, telegram-bot, inline, python-telegram-bot

Here is my code.

```
def start(update, context):
   buttons = [InlineKeyboardButton("Invite User", switch_inline_query="test")]
   update.message.reply_text("Please choose: ", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons))

def button(update, context):
   query = update.callback_query
   print(query)

def main():
   updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)
   updater.dispatcher.add_handler(ChosenInlineResultHandler(button))
```

And I set the bot inline feedback 100%, but in that case I can not send the message to the selected chat.
I'd like to send the button with the switch inline query, but I can not.

Here is my new code:

```
import logging
import os
from unittest import result
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineQueryResultArticle, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, WebAppInfo, Update, LoginUrl
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, ContextTypes, CallbackQueryHandler, ChosenInlineResultHandler, InlineQueryHandler

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
invite_state = False

def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    buttons = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton(
            text="Random Image", 
            switch_inline_query="test"
        ), 
        InlineKeyboardButton(
            "Random Person", 
            callback_data="2"
        )], 
    ]
    update.message.reply_text("Please choose:", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons))

def button (update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    results = [
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=str(uuid4()),
            title="Caps",
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(query.upper()),
        )
    ]
    update.inline_query.answer(results)

def main(receiver_id):
    updater = Updater(os.environ['TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'] , use_context=True)
    updater.bot.send_message(chat_id=receiver_id, text="welcome")
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(InlineQueryHandler(button))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I got error message "Can not find chat" in button function.

Answer (score 0):

I totally solved this problem by using InlineQueryHandler.
So I send the answer with InlineQueryResultArticle and reply_markup with InlineButtons.
Here is the code.

```
def button (update, context):
    query = update.inline_query.query
    buttons = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Invitation", login_url=LoginUrl(url=websiteUrl))]]
    results = [
        InlineQueryResultArticle(
            id=str("123456787654321"),
            title="Send invitation",
            input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(query),
            reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)
        )
    ]
    update.inline_query.answer(results)

Updater.dispatcher.add_handler(InlineQueryHandler(button))
```